# PHP touch() function always returns false

Tags: php, macos, touch

The following code:

```
if (!touch($this->cacheDirectory . '/index.html')) {
$this->error("Could not create the index.html file in the cache directory.");
}
```

always returns the user error in Mac server means the above touch function returns false.

Things that I have verified:

- Creation of file via terminal (unix console) works fine - using touch command.
- The cacheDirectory folder has permission 775.
- The group of this folder is _www and the apache user in Mac is `_www`.

Please help.

Comment: Are you able to create a file in this directory, using fopen?

Comment: to execute a comand you must use  exec("touch path/index.html"); http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: if you're using touch on a unix system, there might be some problems with this: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.touch.php#78606

Comment: @kraysak - I am trying to use PHP built-in function touch() to create a file and I don't want to use exec().

Comment: @Preexo that is something I want to fix. Not sure what is that some problem.

Comment: ok, and can you have an original index.html, and copy it to the new directory?

Comment: @kraysak yes but that is not going to solve my problem, my script creates/deletes a file at different situation.

Comment: well i think you can't really solve this problem since it might be a real PHP-issue that you can't "touch" files with the buildinfunction if you are not the owner of the file. for debugging use the commandline like "sudo -u username php -r "touch('asd.html');"

Comment: I actually get a PHP warning(PHP Warning:  touch(): Unable to create file asd.html because Permission denied in Command line code on line 1") doing this somewhere i don't own the file or directory I'm in... maybe you should put your warning level up to see some more than just "false"

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.touch.php#86781

> Actually, Glen is right, PHP won't touch if it is not the current owner of the file, even if the directory and files are writeable by the PHP user.

So, remove the file and let PHP create it with touch.